# Create a trigger after DELETE and update selected statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger every time a new row is added to an **ArrayA**.

This is the code I used:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER increasement
    AFTER INSERT
    ON ArrayA
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_increasement();
```

A row is added and I need to update a field in an **ArrayB** but the problem is that:
I need to know the ID of the the new row that has been added in order to know which row to increase in ArrayB.

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_increasement()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        UPDATE ArrayB SET number = number + 1 
        WHERE ArrayB.id = ( SELECT ArrayA.arraya_id FROM ArrayA WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ArrayA));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the query that I used for getting the total numbers of the row.

```
    Select Count(*) from ArrayA;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you won't need the condition as you only wish to run a trigger after an `INSERT` event. Also, the initial value in the table `ArrayB` should either be
set to 0 by default or needs a `COALESCE` during the update. Additionally a Trigger should have a `RETURN` statement. You may either return `NEW` or `NULL` for an `AFTER` trigger, but it will fail if you use neither.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_increasement()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
        UPDATE ArrayB SET number = coalesce(number,0) + 1 
            WHERE ArrayB.id =  NEW.arraya_id;
      RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e6051dd3c9ab6fac6c7b193745c46774)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NEW.id which will refer to the currently added row in the table ArrayA

Mysql maintains a reference to the newly added row as NEW in case of Insert query.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a bit?